# How to solve the problem of Dual behavior of django CustomUser in migration?

Tags: django, migration, data-migration, migrate, django-custom-user

I have a data migration as below in which I want to use create_user method of CustomUser, get an instance of the created user, and use this instance to create instance of Partner model.
It is worth mentioning that I have a Partner model that has a one-to-one relationship with CustomUser.
 I have two options:

```
# Option One:

def populate_database_create_partner(apps, schema_editor):
    Partner = apps.get_model('partners', 'Partner')

    CustomUser.objects.create_user(
        id=33,
        email='test_email@email.com',
        password='password',
        first_name='test_first_name',
        last_name="test_last_name",
        is_partner=True,
    )

    u = CustomUser.objects.get(id=33)
    partner = Partner.objects.create(user=u, )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0006_populate_database_createsuperuser'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_database_create_partner),
    ]
```

In option one, I see this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<CustomUser: test_email@email.com>": "Partner.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.
```

I then test this:

```
# Option Two:

def populate_database_create_partner(apps, schema_editor):
    Partner = apps.get_model('partners', 'Partner')
    CustomUser = apps.get_model('accounts', 'CustomUser')


    CustomUser.objects.create_user(
        id=33,
        email='test_email@email.com',
        password='password',
        first_name='test_first_name',
        last_name="test_last_name",
        is_partner=True,
    )

    u = CustomUser.objects.get(id=33)
    partner = Partner.objects.create(user=u, )


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0006_populate_database_createsuperuser'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_database_create_partner),
    ]
```

I the see this error:

```
CustomUser.objects.create_user(
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'create_user'
```

The create_user method does not work.

If I do not use the create_user method and simply use `CustomUser.objects.create(...)`, I will not be able to set password in here.

Comment: also you can try `partner = Partner.objects.create(user_id=33, )` in the first solution

Comment: Put it this way, If I use the model through import, I will be able to use its methods. If I import them through apps.get_model, then methods do not work

Comment: may be you are right, and try to set user by `id`

Comment: I encountered another issue. My Partner model has a custom save method that creates a slug. the slug is not created, because of the same issue! Methods does not work!!!

Comment: I need to replicate it in the migration file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django only keeps limited historical information about each version of your models. One of the things it doesn't keep track of, as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#historical-models), is custom model managers.

The good news is that [there's a way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#model-managers) to force the migrations system to use your custom manager:

> You can optionally serialize managers into migrations and have them available in `RunPython` operations. This is done by defining a `use_in_migrations` attribute on the manager class.

As noted, this just allows your migration to use the version of the manager that exists when the migration is run; so, if you later make changes to it, you could break the migration. A safer alternative is to just copy the relevant `create_user` code into the migration itself.